# Definition of Set of All Random Variables on the same Probability Space for Dummies

Tags: probability, vector-spaces, random-variables

I would like to know if I can understand the **set of all random variables on the same probability space** as the set of all the random variable belonging to the same family of distributions. If know, how can I understand this statement?

Thanks

Comment: By "set of all the random variable belonging to the same family of distributions" to you mean "set of all random variables with the same distribution"? I don't know what you mean by "family of distributions". If so, the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: I meant to be the set of the same shape distributions but with different mean. Anyway, thanks!!

Comment: The answer is still "no". Amongst the set of random variables on some space some random variables may have binomial, Poisson, hypergeometric, normal, etc. distributions.